# (kdb+/q) Is it possible to join or combine rows?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

**Here is my situation:**
I currently have a data table that looks something like this:

```
Symbol    Date          Time             Sequence       Type
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
A      2013.06.06      20:00:00.137   36654383         BestAsk
A      2013.06.06      20:00:00.137   36654383         BestBid
A      2013.06.07      04:00:00.788   3                BestAsk
A      2013.06.07      04:00:00.788   3                BestBid
A      2013.06.07      04:00:00.788   3                BestAsk
A      2013.06.07      04:00:00.788   3                BestBid
A      2013.06.07      07:01:09.584   43126            BestAsk
A      2013.06.07      07:01:09.584   43126            BestBid
A      2013.06.07      07:02:09.012   43431            BestAsk
A      2013.06.07      07:02:09.012   43431            BestBid
```

As you can tell, the rows come in pairs.
Each BestAsk and BestBid row has the same Symbol Date Time and Sequence.
Since they are all sorted all nicely, I am thinking the rows can be combined in relation to their order, but all the join commands I looked at
only combine columns(aj,aj0,etc). I tried flipping the table into a dictionary and then combining in dictionary form but have been unsuccesful.

**What I am looking for in the result is that the identical values Symbol Date Time Sequence don't have to be duplicated  but in the Type column,
show BestAsk and BestBid :**

```
Symbol   Date          Time             Sequence       Type
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
A      2013.06.06      20:00:00.137   36654383          BestAsk,BestBid
A      2013.06.07      04:00:00.788   3                BestAsk,BestBid
A      2013.06.07      04:00:00.788   3                BestAsk,BestBid
A      2013.06.07      07:01:09.584   43126            BestAsk,BestBid
A      2013.06.07      07:02:09.012   43431            BestAsk,BestBid
```

Something like this, Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select distinct Type by Symbol,Date,Time,Sequence from table
```

or use xgroup

Comment: Didn't realize it was that simple, Thanks!

Comment: I am unable to find reference for "by" on the code.kx page, what does it exactly do?